# Confusion with a while statement evaluating if a number is triangular

Tags: java

I've been having troubles trying to figure out how to solve a function. I've been assigned the development of a little programme which tells if a number is "triangular" (a number is triangular when the addition of certain consecutive numbers in the [1,n] interval is n. Following the definition, the number 10 is triangular, because in the [1,10] interval, 1+2+3+4=10).

I've coded this so far:

```
class TriangularNumber{

  boolean numTriangular(int n) {
    boolean triangular = false;
    int i = n;
    while(n>=0 && triangular){
    //UE06 is a class which contains the function "f0", which makes the addition of all the numbers in a determined interval
    UE06 p = new UE06();
      if ((p.f0(1, i))==n)
        triangular = true;
      else
        i=i-1;
    }
    return triangular;
  }

boolean testTriangular = numTriangular(10) == true && 
  numTriangular(7) == false && 
  numTriangular(6) == true;

  public static void main(String[] args){

    TriangularNumber p = new TriangularNumber();
    System.out.println("testTriangular = " + p.testTriangular);
   } 
}
```

According to those boolean tests I made, the function is wrong. As I see the function, it goes like this:

1. I state that the input number in the initial state isn't triangular
   (triangular=false) and i=n (determining the interval [1,i] where the
   function is going to be evaluated
2. While n is greater or equals 0 and the number isn't triangular, the
   loop starts
3. The loop goes like this: if the addition of all the numbers in the
   [1,i] interval is n, the number is triangular, causing the loop to
   end. If that statement is false, i goes from i to (i-1), starting
   the loop again with that particular interval, and so on till the
   addition is n.

I can't spot the error in my "algorithm", any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: If this is a homework assignment please tag it accordingly. Also, what is your question?

Comment: I added the homework tag, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop the condition should be changed to:

```
while(i>=0 && !triangular)
```

Comment: changing this piece in my code solved the error. But I can't seem to understand why I cant put n and just "triangular", isnt whats inside the while statement the "initial state"? thanks a lot!

Comment: @Darkkurama what you have in your while statement is what you describe as: While i is greater or equals 0 (i>=0) and the number isn't triangular (!triangular). You need to use i and not n, as for each iteration your subset is defined by [1;i] and you reduce your subset after each iteration (i=i-1). Otherwise you will be stuck in an infinite loop trying to solve: sum(1,n)=n

Answer (score 4):

`while(n>=0 && triangular){` and `triangular  = false` So, you never execute the function.

Another problem is, if you go in your loop, and the number is not triangular, you never and it, because you test n, but decrease i.

Try again? ;) (It is look like an homework, so, i don't write for you the function, just help you and point some problem in your code)

Comment: Thanks! this helped to understand the while statement with the explanation given by @laguille

Answer (score 1):

I would use maths to avoid needing a loop. The sum of the first n is `n* (n + 1) / 2` so you can estimate what `n` is with `sqrt(n * 2)`

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++)
        if (isTriangular(i))
            System.out.print(i + " ");
    System.out.println();
}

public static boolean isTriangular(int num) {
    // guess the nth for this num.
    int nth = (int) Math.sqrt(num * 2);
    return sumToN(nth) == num;
}

public static int sumToN(int nth) {
    return nth * (nth + 1)/2;
}
```

prints

```
1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55 66 78 91 105 120 136 153 171 190 210 231 253 276 300 325 351 378 406 435 465 496 528 561 595 630 666 703 741 780 820 861 903 946 990
```